# TREE-SEARCH finding key $k$

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that the TREE−SEARCH algorithm ﬁnds a key, if this belongs to a binary search tree to which the algorithm is applied.

I am unsure how to answer this. In our notes it says:

If $k$ is the key and it exists in the tree, then it is found. Worst case is that $k$ is in the deepest leaf of the tree. So

Search time $\leq$ Height of tree + $1$

If tree is balanced, then let $h$ be the height of tree. Then tree has $2^{h+1} -1 = n$ vertices. And then it just finds $h$.

But I don't know how much of this is actually relevant to answering the question.

Comment: Hmmm...Can you prove that your traversal routine visits every node in the tree? If so, you're done.

Comment: im really not sure how to do that...

Comment: To "search" a tree, you have to traverse it. Have they taught you in-order, pre-order, post-order traversal? I would do this by contradiction: Assume that a node contains the key k but is not reachable by any traversal. Therefore...

Comment: We know what the INORDER-TREE-WALK algorithm is. And if it is not reachable by any traversal, doesn't that mean $k$ does not exist since a traversal would hit every node.

Comment: Exactly. Thus, if you traverse the tree, and one of the nodes of the tree contains the key you are searching for, you must find it. (There is *no* node that is not reachable).

Comment: That seems so easy... but thanks a lot though.